# Create Dynamic List of Business Dates Since Arbitrary Start Date in Access

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Using MS Access 2010, I need to generate a complete list of dates from an arbitrary start date, say #1/1/2015#, to now, Date().  I would like this list to live in its own table, although a query would work, too.  I also would prefer to only grab business days/week days.  Can anyone help?

I'm tracking business process errors by date.  A new error record is made for each error, and each record is tagged with a date.  However, there is not an error on every date.  So reporting over time does not give a correct visualization, as the dates without errors are not represented.

I appreciate help generating this list in Access, as well as any alternative ideas for representing this information.

Cheers,
Burgess

Update - I've been able to make a list of dates since a start date.  Here's my code:

```
Sub createDatesTable()

    'Declare variables'
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim countDate As Date
    Dim length As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dates() As Date

    'Initialize'
    startDate = #6/23/2015#
    endDate = #9/1/2015#
    countDate = startDate
    length = endDate - startDate

    'Define date array length'
    ReDim dates(1 To length)

    'Generate date list in array'
    For i = 1 To (length)
        dates(i) = countDate
        countDate = countDate + 1
    Next i

    'Print array to Immediate Window'
    For i = 1 To length
        Debug.Print dates(i)
    Next i


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblDateList", dbOpenDynaset)

    'Add array data to existing table'
    For i = 1 To length
        rs.AddNew
        rs!DateList = dates(i)
        rs.Update
    Next i

    rs.Close
    db.Close

End Sub
```

Now, I'm very new to VBA, so this may well contain elementary mistakes.  Thanks for the feedback.

-Burgess

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post any attempted solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table can have a structure like this:

```
Column name    | Data type
---------------+----------
dt             | DateTime
isBusinessDay  | Yes/No
```

And as for the filling, something like this:

```vb
public sub fillDates(startDate as date, endDate as date)
    dim db as DAO.database, rs as DAO.Recordset
    dim strSQL as string
    dim d as date

    strSQL = "delete from tbl_dates"
    docmd.runsql strSQL

    set db = currentdb()
    set rs = db.openRecordset("tbl_dates", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    for d = startDate to endDate
        with rs
            .addNew
            ![dt] = d
            ![isBusinessDay] = (format(d, "w", vbMonday) <= 5)
            .update
        end with
    next d
    rs.close
    db.close
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks Barranka.  This looks much simpler than what I was able to conjure up with arrays and editing a table.  I especially like your approach with isBusinessDay for filtering.  I'm going to add this to my code now.